# Null values are not being detected in csv laravel queue

Tags: mysql, laravel, laravel-queue

I'm facing an issue while uploading csv file with the help of laravel queue jobs. Problem is that when I don't enter some value in csv and it is in the form of ,, I have a check **isset($item[10])** which will check if $item[10] has value or not but it is not working actually. It is still submitting in mysql table with value null. I've tried **!empty($item[10])** as well as **!($item[10]==null)** and **!($item[10]=='')** but not working.
Thank you for your kind help.

```
public function handle()
{

    foreach ($this->chuck_data as $item){

        if (isset($item[10])) {
                
            bucket_comment::create([
                'bucket_id' => $claim_file->id,
                'disposition_id' => $dispo_id,
                'disposition_name' => $disposition,
                'followup_date' => $item[13],
                'comment' => !empty($item[10]) ? $item[10] : null,
                'bucket_com_create' => Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')->format('m/d/Y g:i A'),
                'create_date' => Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')->format('Y-m-d'),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Do a `var_dump($item[10]);` and find out what is actually in that variable

Comment: Thank you for your reply. It is giving string(0) ""

Comment: Then empty() should work but set will not work as if `$item[10]` exists, set will be true

Comment: Also `$item[10] != ''` should work sa well

Comment: But both are not working as they are passing null value to database

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this will cleanup your code.

```php
public function handle()
{
   
    foreach ($this->chuck_data as $item){
        $comment = trim($item[10]) ?: null;
        //Checking if comment existed on not
        if ($comment) {
            bucket_comment::create([
                'bucket_id' => $claim_file->id,
                'disposition_id' => $dispo_id,
                'disposition_name' => $disposition,
                'followup_date' => $item[13],
                'comment' => $comment,
                'bucket_com_create' => Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')->format('m/d/Y g:i A'),
                'create_date' => Carbon::now('Asia/Kolkata')->format('Y-m-d'),
            ]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worked for me. I cleared the cache and restart the queue after applying this solution and it worked. Great! Thank you!